# O(1) Delete operation

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

Is there any data structure or variation of existing data structure that offers O(1) or constant time complexity for delete operation ?

I know hash table can do it. But I am modifying hash table where, we can get all the  the keys without going through all the buckets and in order to do so I am storing every key in another linked list and at the time when I add it to hash table. So I can get all the keys in quick.

Comment: It is hard to know if you are looking for specific element delete [element given as input]? minimum delete? first/last element delete?

Comment: @amcnabb: That is what they asked me in an interview :(

Comment: "But I am modifying hash table where we can get all the the keys without going through all the buckets"  This sounds nonstandard.  Could you please post details on how you accomplish this?  And which elements you are choosing to delete (as per the suggestion by @amit)?

Comment: @amit: I have given the key that I want to delete. Only condition is it should be done in constant time.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: yes, this is not standard, its modification to exiting concept. In order to get all keys without going through all buckets, I have suggested to use additional data structure, so I used Linked List to hold all keys. I added keys to this linked list at the time Hash Table is first created.

Comment: @SumitLonkar From your question and comments I gather that you know the key, and you already have the hash table implementation, which has O(1) deletion.  And you want to delete that key from the table in O(1) time.  So what's the question?

Answer (score 3):

What about HashSets? They offer constant time performance for add/remove/contains/size.

In java, it is called a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: Dont they vary in time when there are collisions? (Granted you want to avoid those... but yeah).

Comment: Yes they do, but collisions usually mean you either have an awful hash function (fixable) or you have a huge dataset (which other data structures would then have the same problem).  Not sure about hashSet, but for hashMaps, upon collisions, the new value gets appended to a list, which then offers a O(n) add/delete runtime (still not too bad...).

Comment: @DKT Most solid hash table implementations (including the Java HashSet) automatically resize the table so that the load factor is roughly constant.  So even with a large dataset the overall runtime is still amortized O(1).

Comment: @James: Ya they do adjust themselves when collision occurs, but as per I know they just double the number of buckets and everything get rehashed...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I am following - it seems you want to maintain both linked list of your elements, so you can iterate them quickly - and still get `O(1)` - so you use a HashSet for that.

You are on the right track. In java what you are describing is called a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

The idea is: You have 2 data structures:

1. LinkedList [doubly linked list] of Elements
2. HashMap:Elements->Nodes - each key in the hash map is mapped to the corresponding node in the linked list.

Using this DS, you get the following ops:

```
add(x):
  if map.containsKey(x):
    return
  list.addLast(x)
  map.put(x,list.getLastNode()) 

delete(x):
  if (map.containsKey(x) == false):
    return
  list.deleteNode(map.get(x))
  map.delete(x)
```

Note that both add and delete are `O(1)`, they are doing only final number of `O(1)` ops on the map and list.

Comment: The big question here is the implementation of `list.deleteNode()`, isn't it?

Comment: @FrankFarmer: It is fairly easy in doubly linked list, you get the actual node as input, so all you have to do is `node.next.prev = node.prev` and `node.prev.next = node.next` [and `delete node`]. [of course you need to check first if node is the head or tail - but it can be still done in `O(1)`]

Comment: @amit: But again you will have to traverse through doubly linked list to find that key to delete which is o(n) worst case...

Comment: @SumitLonkar no. tou find the reference to the exact node in O(1) using the hashmap!! no need to traverse the list in delete nor insert

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse there is, but with the **mother of all caveats**.

A simple array of nodes, with deleted nodes having a `deleted` flag has constant delete time but, and this is the caveat, it has extremly bad time requirements on all other operations.

**Edit**

The answer originally talked of a **sorted** array, but this was the wrong choice of words (sorry, non-english native). I meant **indexed** as in the classic case of an array (think C) - essentially meaning that there is no hidden O(>1) in accessing the array elements (to set the deleted flag).

Another point: I am talking of deletion only, not search-and-delete

Comment: This example doesn't really hold.  To find the element to delete, you need to perform a binary search, which takes log time.  Yes, setting the flag is a constant-time operation once you have found the element, but that's the case whether the list is sorted or not.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin The question doesn't ask about finding the element, it asks about deleting it. The assumption that you need to find it first is reasonable, but not necessarily correct: it's wrong if the decision to delete an element is made while iterating over the array.

Comment: @hvd Oops.  My mistake.  I'm deleting the mistaken comment (can't edit) and I'll just post the useful part.

Comment: Useful part of my previous comment: A deletion *is* cheap once you've found the element, but this answer explicitly calls out a sorted list. Why specify that the list has to be sorted unless you care about finding the element in the list?

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Useful part of my previous comment: good point :)

Comment: My bad, the word "sorted" was a wrong choice, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several.  Deleting the top element of a stack is O(1), which is valid because you only have access to the top of the stack.  Hash tables also have amortized O(1) deletion for any element of the table.

Comment: Deleting that object is O(1) or removing it from the stack is O(1) (And come to think of it, which one is he asking about I wonder?)

Comment: @James I mean removing from the stack, but "deleting" from any data structure means removing from the data structure.  Truly deleting data  (i.e. making the data unavailable to other code) is language-specific.  However, this question doesn't specify a tag for a particular language.

Comment: So as you mentioned, any data structure where you do not have to iterate through it will be O(1) in this context?

Comment: @James If you don't have to iterate at all, then deletion *is* O(1).  However, there are a lot of cases where the iteration is hidden.  To delete an element from an array, for instance, you have to shift all the later elements in the array, so you're really iterating through it.  The classic linked list from FP doesn't have this issue: if you implement a stack with a linked list, you simply set the head pointer one element forward to delete the head of the stack.  Constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for selective (per object) deletion at that O notation? My thoughts are if this is a large collection of objects needed for X time but after that they are all dropped, then a memory pool that you can just mark as 'free' with the understanding that all memory allocated from it is now invalid, would work (used this when unloading a level for a game in preparation to load a new one if you want an example.)

A memory pool is just a block of memory of a specific size generally for a specific purpose. The hardest part is writing the allocation routines for it, and potentially the deallocation. But when you are completely done with that pool, you can simply reset the tracking information to effectively 'wipe' all of its data and make it free/available again.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashSet or LinkedHashMap.
HashSet internally uses HashMap, so if you dont want a key you could use Hashset.
LinkedHashMap maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map, and the Map gives you the faster Search access to keys. 
the Java Defined library class does not gives the direct enqueue and dequeue functionality out of the box, but with little modification to the source code you could get answer to the question.